# What's the most efficient way to find the next element in a jQuery selector list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery selector of arbitrary complexity:

```
// a bunch of links:
var list = $('#foo').find('li.bar a, li.baz a');
```

I have a handle on one element within that list:

```
// the 11th such link:
var current = list.slice(10, 11);
```

What's the most efficient way to find the links *before* and *after* in `list`? Keep in mind that the selector is *live* and that entries may be added or removed between getting `current` and trying to find the next or previous link.

The best I can come up with is a O(n) traversal of `list`:

```
function adjacentInList(list, target, direction) {
  var delta = (direction === 'prev' ? -1 : 1);
  list = $(list);
  target = $(target);
  var result = null;
  list.each(function(index, element) {
    if (target[0] === element) {
      result = list.slice(index + delta, index + delta + 1);
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forked Steve Wellens example. Mine is a bit nastier but maintains the same interface and offers the flexibility of working with a changing DOM.

http://jsfiddle.net/sJwJL/

Primary function:

```
var itr = function(selector){
    var last_element = null;
    return {
        next : function(){
            var elements = $(selector);
            var last_index = 0;
            if(last_element != null){
                elements.each(function(item){
                    if(item == last_element){
                        last_index = index+1;
                        return;
                    }
                });
            }
            last_element = $(elements[last_index]);
            return last_element;
        }
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's also O(n) complexity, but wouldn't the syntax would be much simpler using `.index()`?

```
function next() {
   var currList = $(list.selector),
       idx = currList.index(current);
   return idx >= 0 && idx < currList.length-1 ?
       currList.slice(idx+1,idx+2) : undefined;
}

function prev() {
   var currList = $(list.selector),
       idx = currList.index(current);
   return idx > 0 ? 
       currList.slice(idx - 1, idx) : undefined;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/yAFr5/12/ for the full example.

Comment: What happens when the list changes length *while* you're iterating? I'm pretty sure that jQuery's `$.each` handles that case, but this won't.

Comment: Looking at the jQuery code for `.each()`, it's also doing a `for` loop iteration - so I don't think it would be any better at handling an asynchronous DOM insertion than my code would. A jQuery selector is still essentially an array - you'd need something more like a linked list to get better than O(n) and deal with the insertion issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit klunky but works:

http://jsfiddle.net/zHDws/

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work if elements are added to the list. I believe next is using an index under the hood not doing an HTMLElement comparison.

Comment: That definitely does not work because the elements in my selector are not necessarily siblings. `next()` finds the next sibling.